# Problema com o FileUpload

Tags: java, hibernate, jsf-2.2

Tive a oportunidade de encontra uma aplicação pronta na internet como mostra abaixo:

https://github.com/wladyband/Produtos/blob/master/Produtos/src/com/wordpress/programandojava/controller/ProdutoBean.java

Porém sou novo como programador Java, tentei adaptar a aplicação do meu jeito, mas não tive sucesso.

Aplicação tem que adicionar o nome, o valor e a imagem tudo em uma entidade, quando o usuário adiciona o registro a aplicação consegue salvar todos os dados inclusive a imagem no banco, mas quando é para mostra em tela gera um problema, dê uma olhada na imagem a baixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Essa imagem com o nome de teste333 não era para aparece, eu tinha incluído outra imagem. Mas porque essa imagem apareceu ai?

Porque eu tinha adicionado ela num ultimo teste, mas não era para aparecer no registro do nome teste333, era para ser outra imagem.

Quando adicionei o quarto registro aconteceu isso:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ele colocou as imagens na ordem correta e não mostrou a ultima imagem.

Acredito que o erro esteja nesse método.

```
public void processFileUpload(FileUploadEvent uploadEvent) {

    try {

        ServletContext sContext = (ServletContext) FacesContext
                .getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getContext();

        File folder = new File(sContext.getRealPath("/temp"));
        if (!folder.exists())
            folder.mkdirs();

        for (Produto f : produtos) {
            String nomeArquivo = f.getId() + ".jpg";
            String arquivo = sContext.getRealPath("/temp") + File.separator
                    + nomeArquivo;

            criaArquivo(f.getImagem(), arquivo);
        }
        produto.setImagem(uploadEvent.getFile().getContents());
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

O problema está lógica e estou precisando de ajuda para corrigir a lógica.

Essa é minha pagina:

```xml
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head>
    <style type="text/css">
.ui-widget {
    font-size: 11px !important;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Tahoma;
    font-weight: light;
}
</style>
</h:head>

<h:body>

    <p:ajaxStatus
        style="width:64px;height:64px;position:fixed;right:5px;bottom:5px">
        <f:facet name="start">
            <p:graphicImage value="/images/loading.gif" />
        </f:facet>

        <f:facet name="complete">
            <h:outputText value="" />
        </f:facet>
    </p:ajaxStatus>

    <h:form id="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <p:growl id="msgs" showDetail="false" showSummary="true" />

        <p:panel>
            <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                <h:outputText value="Nome:" />
                <p:inputText value="#{mbProduto.produto.nome}" />

                <h:outputText value="Preço:" />
                <p:inputText value="#{mbProduto.produto.preco}" />

                <h:outputText value="Foto: " />
                <p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{mbProduto.processFileUpload}"
                    label="Escolher" cancelLabel="Cancelar" sizeLimit="400000"
                    invalidSizeMessage="Imagem muito grande" auto="true"
                    invalidFileMessage="Tipo de imagem não suportado"
                    allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(jpe?g|png)$/" />



                <p:commandButton value="Salvar" action="#{mbProduto.salvaProduto()}"
                    update=":form:msgs, :form:dtProdutos, :form" />
                <p:commandButton value="Limpar" onclick="form.reset()" />
            </h:panelGrid>
        </p:panel>

        <p:dataTable id="dtProdutos" value="#{mbProduto.produtos}" var="p"
            style="text-align: center;" emptyMessage="Nenhum produto cadastrado.">
            <p:column headerText="ID" style="width:2%; font-weight: bold;">
                <h:outputText value="#{p.id}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Nome" style="width:14%">
                <h:outputText value="#{p.nome}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Preço" style="width:14%">
                <h:outputText value="#{p.preco}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="foto" style="width:24%">
                <p:graphicImage value="/temp/#{p.id}.jpg" cache="false" width="100"
                    height="50" />
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>


    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Amigo já passei por isso e não era nada errado no código e sim a versão do `primefaces` que eu estava usando o componomente `p:graphicImage` não atualizava tentar fazer `update` na versão do `primefaces`.

Answer (score 1):

A imagem não alterou porque você gravou outra imagem com o mesmo nome, então o navegador usa a imagem que está em cache. Um truque para atualizar sempre a imagem é colocar um texto aleatório como parâmetro após a imagem, por exemplo a data atual:

`<p:graphicImage value="/temp/#{p.id}.jpg?#{data_atual}" cache="false" width="100" height="50" />`

No código acima `?` indica que o que vem a seguir são parâmetros e data_atual é uma variável qualquer por exemplo uma contendo new Date(). Apesar de que eu acho que cache="false" já não deveria deixar cache, talvez seja algum bug.

De acordo com o seu código parece que está sendo criada uma imagem em uma pasta temporária e gravando os bits no banco de dados. Da forma do seu código a imagem exibida é a que está na pasta temporária. Para carregar do banco deveria se fazer alguns ajustes:

Na classe Produto:

```
public StreamedContent getImagem() throws IOException {
        BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(this.imagem);
        File file = new File("imagem");
        ImageIO.write(img, "jpg", file);
        FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream(file);
        return new DefaultStreamedContent(fi);
    }
```

Na tela:

```
<p:graphicImage value="#{mbProduto.produto.imagem}" width="100" height="50" />
```